# Why is the stream blocking in this iex session?

Tags: csv, elixir

I'm trying to parse some CSVs using elixir:

```
 iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2] [source-e6dd627] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.3.0-dev) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> a = File.stream!("test/lib/fit_notes/fit_notes_export.csv") |> CSV.decode
#Function<49.97003610/2 in Stream.transform/3>
iex(2)> Stream.take(a, 1)
#Stream<[enum: #Function<49.97003610/2 in Stream.transform/3>,
 funs: [#Function<38.97003610/1 in Stream.take/2>]]>
iex(3)> Enum.take(a, 1)  
[["Date", "Exercise", "Category", "Weight (kgs)", "Reps", "Distance",
  "Distance Unit", "Time"]]
iex(4)> Enum.take(a, 2)
^ this just blocks
```

The first `Enum.take` that I issue works, the second blocks forever. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm using [this library](https://github.com/beatrichartz/csv) for CSV parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the example from http://hexdocs.pm/csv/CSV.html
your code would end up something like this:

```
a = File.stream!("test/lib/fit_notes/fit_notes_export.csv") |> CSV.decode |>
Stream.take(1) |>
Stream.take(1) |>
Enum.take(2)
```

Note I changed your first `Enum.take(1)` in to a `Stream.take(1)`  so that the Stream doesn't get prematurely terminated. Also note doing two `Stream.take(1)` will be better converted into a single `Stream.take(2)`.  Also note how the stream piping works by adding a |> to the end of the each line until you reach an Enum call - which then fires the whole operation.

*Added:*
For Streams with side-effects (like logging) see
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/1831 where they recommend Stream.each

Comment: is it possible to inspect the stream state from iex? or to rewind/restart it?

Comment: Elxir's streams are just a syntactic way to compose list processing - specially designed to allow you to consume list of unknown length without having to wait til the end.  AFAIK you can't inspect a Stream in iex because it is still being composed.  Probably what you want to do is see some content while the stream is running. You can do that by using something like Stream.each and specifying a function to it  that either prints or writes the current content to a logfile. Else you can send the content to a different process that receives and reports it later.

Comment: ...  In any case that Stream.each can "return" the current content to the next step in the Stream  - so it can continue as normal.